# Why can’t Voyager crew beam in new lungs for neelix?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In Episode 4, Season 1 of Voyager, Neelix gets attacked by a species that beams out his lungs.

As a hot fix, the holographic doctor creates a hologram of his lungs, based on a recent Transporter log.

If the transporter logs are detailed enough to create holographic lungs, why couldn’t the crew use the transporter to materialize a second pair of lungs for neelix?

From my understanding of beaming, the information can be materialized independent of the dematerialiazation. The second Riker from TNG is an example of the materialization process being independent from the dematerialization process.

Comment: The dupe Riker was a total fluke

Comment: In-universe, I'm sure someone can come up with enough technobabble to sound plausible. Out-of-universe, technology is only as capable (or limited) as the plot requires.

Comment: I don’t believe this is a duplicate answer. Replicators and transporters aren’t the same thing. If the rule that applied to replicators were true for transporters, then that tech would be limited to inanimate object and not crewmen who clearly are Alive and well after being transported. Taking a lung from recent transporter logs seems absolutely plausible.